# JSF get username of windows logged user ldap

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I want to create application that doesn't have manually authentication. The application have to use the username of the current logged windows user. Maybe I must configure to connect to the ldap server or something else but I don't know how to do it. I tried to get the username:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
```

but expected it is not working.

Comment: This is not the responsibility of JSF, but of the application server where the JSF website is running on. Just contact and consult the server admin. He's the one responsible for configuring the server in such way that the LDAP login is transparently performed so that you end up getting the right remote user. Note that this works only when you're *actually* running a Windows based Intranet, for obvious reasons. This is at least not a programming problem, but a server config problem. If you happen to be the server admin yourself (... really?), rather consult http://serverfault.com if you stucks.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the remote user only works when a user is signed in. Have you configured the security in the web.xml and your application server? JAAS will be your friend, depending on the server you can configure JAAS together with SPNEGO.